# javascript if number is evenly divisible true if not false

Tags: javascript

I have to write Java script that can read two integers from the user, if the first number the user entered is evenly divisible by the second number, then it will display an alert of TRUE to the user, and FALSE otherwise. If either number the user enters is ZERO the alert should display FALSE to the user.

this is my code it does not work

```
        var y = prompt("Enter a Value","");
      var z = prompt("Enter a Value","");

      if  (y % z === 0) {
      greeting = "TRUE";
      } else (y % z !== 0 ||
      {
      greeting = "FALSE"
      document. get Element By Id ("true false").inner HTML = greeting;
```

Comment: please provide the details of the code.

Comment: your coding is incomplete ! provide more

Answer (score 2):

> If either number the user enters is ZERO the alert should display
>   FALSE to the user.

change you if condition to

```
if  (x && y && y % z === 0) {
```

Rest of the code is

```
if  (x && y && y % z === 0) 
{
   greeting = "TRUE";
}
else
{
   greeting = "FALSE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to javascript here is another way to implement this very common pattern using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var greeting = (x && y && y % z === 0) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```